# How to order sql query from 1 line to user friendly?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

How a problem with reading sql queries in our project. There are really long sql queries in project. While debugging i copy to sql query string from visual studio to ms sql server management studio but when i paste it it becomes one really long line. And its almost impossible to break the lines to multiple lines so it would be readeable. Is there any tool that takes a string sql query and convert it multiple lines so its easyly readeable?

Comment: Most people recommend [sqlparse](http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/)

Comment: There is a website to solve your problem [here](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm), but I don't know if their have any restriction with the length of a SQL - statement.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you would normally do in a text editor - for example, in Notepad++, you can do Edit > Line Operations > Split Lines. Which text editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Why is it impossible to break it into multiple lines?

In C#, you can have multi-line strings like this:

```
string SQL = @"SELECT col1, col2, col3
               FROM tbl2
               WHERE col1='" + foo + @"'
               ORDER BY col1 DESC";
```

Comment: yes i know the problem is while debugging i have that string. and i wanna execute on sql server management studio. but when i coppy it to sql sms it copies as a single really long line and its really unreadable. Sorry if i couldnt be clearer

Comment: @deed02392 this sample didn't solve his problem in management studio

Comment: Ah yes, well in that case a formatter would probably do the job, like http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Presumably the issue is with the line breaks not being copied or retained when autoformatting. Using that site as an intermediate step should resolve your issues.

Comment: Of course, you wouldn't really want to leave yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters) like that in production code.